# Getting tasks in the order in which they appear in a task list

Tags: sharepoint

In SharePoint task lists, we can Move Up or Move Down a task in the list. The web part in AllItems.aspx remembers the sequence. How do we retrieve (using CAML queries) the sequence in which these items appear?

Edit: I have tried ordering by date modified but apparently changing the order in which they appear in the task list does not influence this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CAML query allows to retrieve items in the same order as they have been adjusted via `Move Up/Move Down` buttons:

```
<Query>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Order" Ascending="TRUE"/>
    </OrderBy>
</Query>
```

Task list contains column called `Order` that stores those settings.

Here is an example that utilizes JSOM API:

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var items = list.getItems(createOrderQuery());
ctx.load(items);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        //print items
        items.get_data().forEach(function(item){
            console.log(item.get_item('Title')); 
        });
    },
    function(sender,args){
        console.log(args.get_message());
    }); 


function createOrderQuery(){
    var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
    qry.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Order" Ascending="TRUE"/></OrderBy></Query></View>');
    return qry;
}
```

Comment: Is the Order column really a default column? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I could get the value of the Order column by using get_item('Order') , but interestingly using the Order column in the OrderBy section in a CAML query does not seem to work.